# Selecting a column to make histogram

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

1. I have a data set that has 28 columns. I need to select one column (Age) and make a histogram with it.
2. My problem is that how to select only the age column.

I tried multiple ways. But it always selects all the 28 columns and draws the histogram. How i only select one column? any help will be great.

Also can you please explain how to use data.loc method to select a column?

I used it as:

```
df.loc[df['OS_STATUS'] == "LIVING", " 
AGE"].value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind ='bar')
```

but I don't know how to make it work. any advice will be good.

This is what i have so far:

```
cereal = pd.read_excel( 'C:\\Users\\f- 
PC\\Desktop\\class\\CS\\hw1\\Book2.xlsx')
cereal.plot(kind = 'bar')
plt.ylabel('frequency')
plt.xlabel('age')
plt.title('histogram')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Since you didn't provide a sample data (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ) `df.loc[df['OS_STATUS'] == "LIVING", "AGE"]` should produce a series, can you corroborate?

Answer (score 3):

Try this example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1166/stuff/titanic.csv')
df['Age'].hist()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: it compiles but i dont get any output in the form of histogram.

Comment: add `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` then the end add `plt.show()`

Comment: df['Age'].hist(bins = 20), by doing so you can specify the number of bins